# Do i need a server in order to have team synchronization in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, repository

Svn? CVS? Team sync? Or is there another simpler way to sync a projects between 2 computers without a server?

Comment: Use [Git](http://git-scm.com)?

Comment: Git is a modern, distributed version control system that is supersedes SVN and CVS. Everybody uses it these days.

Comment: It doesnt require a server? Can i use it in Eclipse?

Comment: It doesn't *require* a server (but it makes it easier if you have one). See [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

Comment: Cool but how do i add a user to get synched with my projects

Comment: Read [Pro Git](http://progit.org/). Other people have written better tutorials about Git than I can provide.